# Missing net_4_5\mscorlib.dll.so when compiling Mono source

Tags: linux, mono, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get the latest mono (version 3.12.0) to compile on my raspberry pi 2 running raspbian linux (based on debian).

I've downloaded the mono source and compiling seems to be going well then I hit an error when compiling 'mcs/class/aot-compiler'

the error is that it cannot find './../../class/lib/net_4_5/mscorlib.dll.so'

I've checked the directory and I see that mscorlib.dll was compiled along with an .mdb file but I do not see an so file.

Do I need to specify a switch or something to build the so file? (I'm a linux newb)

Where is the make file that's building mscorlib? compiling is taking forever for the whole source, can I just recompile mscorlib and have an `so` file emitted somehow?